# why insert time in go-pg is changed

Tags: go, go-pg

I want to insert time to database using go-pg, but value is change after inserted.

```
toRound := time.Now()
date := time.Date(toRound.Year(), toRound.Month(), toRound.Day(), 0, 0, 0, 0, toRound.Location())
```

value of `date` is `2020-03-18 00:00:00 +0700 WIB`

and to insert using `go-pg`

```
reportMessage := &ReportMessage{
                    Total:      ii,
                    Date:            date
                }

_, err = p.ormer.Model(reportMessage).Returning("id").Insert()
```

value of `date` after inserted is `2020-03-17 17:00:00+00:00:00`

it's looks like because of timezone

how to insert time exactly as raw value without affected by timezone or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use an UTC date in model:

```
reportMessage.Date := date.UTC()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to let the go-pg ORM to handle this automatically. If you define your model like:

```
type ReportMessage struct {
    // Your data fields here

    CreatedAt time.Time `pg:"default:now()" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `pg:"default:now()" json:"updated_at`
}
```

This will tell go-pg / Postgres to use `now()` whenever a new record is inserted. You can then handle timezone and stuff in your code while the database will always keep the timestamp in UTC. You might need your server's time to be properly configured by using NTP or similar.